# Select data from database and give error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want get from database table row `name` but in it i get error. (`$query->code_airline` => is other query as select from database table row)

code:

```
<?=$this->db->get_where('ticket_code', array( 'code' => $query->code_airline ))->row()->name?>
```

error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity: Notice
>  Message: Trying
>   to get property of non-object
>  Filename: core/Loader.php(679) :
>   eval()'d code
>  Line Number: 48

If want use it as:

```
<?php //This is line 49
    $ca = echo $query->code_airline;
    $query_tc = $this->db->get_where('ticket_code', array( 'code' => $ca ))->row();
    echo $query_tc->name;
?>
```

have this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\system\core\Loader.php(679) : eval()'d code on line 49

How can fix it?

**Update:**

i use as:

```
<?php
    $ca = $query->code_airline;
    $query_tc = $this->db->get_where('ticket_code',array('code'=>$ca));
    $row = $query_tc->row(); //This is line 52
    echo $row->name;

?>
```

i have this error with above php code:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity: Notice
>  Message: Trying
>   to get property of non-object
>  Filename: core/Loader.php(679) :
>   eval()'d code
>  Line Number: 52

Comment: your first code fragment is the ugliest use of the poor language of PHP I've ever seen. Breaking every bloody rule of code consistency in the world.

Comment: Ok, please see my new code and give me comment about error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't ECHO in a variable assignment

```
 $ca = $query->code_airline;  //no echo here!
```

Also, I believe you're doing something wrong in calling $query->code_airline, but you didn't provide your code so I'm just guessing.

**Suggestion:** chaining is a nice feature but can be confusing, especially if written as one-liner. First of all, write it in full, you can "compact" your code later if you feel so; keep in mind readability and maintenability also:

```
$query_tc = $this->db->get_where('ticket_code',array('code'=>$ca));
// $ca is the value assigned above. Make sure you're calling $query->code_airline correctly, as per my suggestion.
$row = $query_tc->row();
echo $row->name;
```

**UPDATE:**
you might want to be sure that there are actually any result.

```
   $query_tc = $this->db->get_where('ticket_code',array('code'=>$ca));
   // $ca is the value assigned above. Make sure you're calling $query->code_airline correctly, as per my suggestion.
   if ($query_tc->num_rows() > 0)
   {
     $row = $query_tc->row();
     echo $row->name;
   }
   else
   {
     //do something else
   }
```

Comment: I have new error, see my update in post and please tell me that what do i do?